# Why is there not a delta here in this formula about temperature changes

Tags: energy, temperature, conventions

I have been taught and have seen this formula many times
$$Q=m\cdot c\cdot\Delta T$$
Where $Q$ is the internal energy, $m$ is the mass, $c$ is the specific heat and $\Delta T$ is the temperature.

However to me it seems like this formula would make a lot more sense if it looked like this:
$$\Delta Q=m\cdot c\cdot\Delta T$$
Since 1 kg of water at 70 degrees obviously contains some energy, but if we didn't change the energy then it says the energy is zero. However with a $\Delta Q$ instead we simply say that the amount that the energy changed is zero, which makes sense. Why is the formula normally written without a $\Delta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Q$ is not the internal energy, but the heat exchanged (absorbed or given away). We use it when we put something near something at a different temperature: the heat exchanged is $Q$. Instead,the internal energy is called $U$, and if we heat something up, then the $\Delta U$ is positive.